# Skipping sheets with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am given excel workbooks on a weekly basis. Now these workbooks could have as little as 3 sheets but an unlimited maximum. I know the values of the first two sheets as they never change. So I would like to skip reading those two sheets. My thought is to get all sheet names but count them individually and place that into a counter then simply start a comparison at 2

I used a while loop thinking i can just iterate through the sheets and add to the counter variable however it always returns 0 and I know the workbook has about 40 sheets

```
for f in xFiles:
    #print(f)
    i = 0
    #Grabs just Reported Users
    info = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name = None)
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(f)

    while xls.sheet_names == True:
        i += 1
    print(i)
```

When I gets printed all that shows is 0 currently

Comment: maybe try out `for sheet in xls.sheet_names:`

Comment: So you mean do a nested for loop rather than the while?

Comment: Tried that and it worked thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.ExcelFile(f).sheet_names` returns a list. So to loop through it:

```
for sheet in xls.sheet_names:
    i+=1
    # xls.parse(sheet)
    print(i)
```